# How to add 1 min ohlc data generated to be grouped to historical data sequentially

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, candlestick-chart

I have generated 2 min historical data of a script and 1 min ohlc data from ticks of an equity.
But I was struck at clubbing the both dataframes, as i want  agreggating 1 min ohlc data need to clubbed sequentialy to histrorical data.

Output of Historical data

```
                      date    open    high     low   close   fast_ema   slow_ema  slow_sma
0     2021-06-03 22:52:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
1     2021-06-03 22:54:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
2     2021-06-03 22:56:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
3     2021-06-03 22:58:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
...                   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...        ...        ...       ...
13920 2021-07-29 21:22:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0  5448.7956  5443.4555   5425.56
13921 2021-07-29 21:24:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0  5449.2365  5444.1414   5426.07
13922 2021-07-29 21:26:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0  5449.9892  5444.9467   5426.57
13923 2021-07-29 21:28:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0  5449.9914  5445.4061   5427.08
13924 2021-07-29 21:30:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0  5450.3931  5446.0056   5427.55

[13924 rows x 8 columns]
```

Lets say its code as :   `df3=pd.DataFrame(data)`

Output of i min candle, ohlc data

```py
{
    58375943: {
        datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 29, 21, 43): {'high': 5451.0, 'low': 5450.0, 'open': 5450.0, 'close': 5451.0},
        datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 29, 21, 44): {'high': 5451.0, 'low': 5451.0, 'open': 5451.0, 'close': 5451.0}
    }
}
```

Lets say its code as : `df = pd.DataFrame(candle,index=[0])`

I want to club these both datas , so that each 1 min data generated in df = pd.DataFrame(candle,index=[0]) need to be added to df3=pd.DataFrame(data) with iterating index count ie;
[13924 rows x 8 columns]
13924 row +1  and so on for each df row.

My code as below. But it is generating only  row in df from each imin timeframe and same clubbing to first index of df3 dataframe and further the same row is replacing on each minute rather than adding rows.

code is as below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(candle,index=[0])
df.drop(df.columns[[0,6]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.rename(columns = {'Time':'date'}, inplace = True)
print("data: \n",df)
global rows
dfs = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    df_cols = ['date','open','high','low','close']
    d = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=df_cols,index=[])
    dfs.append(df)
print(dfs)
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df1,df3])
print ("Final dataframe: \n",df2)
```

output Final dataframe:

Final:

```
                      date    open    high     low   close   fast_ema   slow_ema  slow_sma
0     2021-07-29 21:42:00  5450.0  5450.0  5448.0  5449.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
0     2021-06-03 22:52:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
1     2021-06-03 22:54:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
2     2021-06-03 22:56:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
3     2021-06-03 22:58:00  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0  5071.0        NaN        NaN       NaN
...                   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...        ...        ...       ...
13920 2021-07-29 21:22:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0  5448.7956  5443.4555   5425.56
13921 2021-07-29 21:24:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0  5449.2365  5444.1414   5426.07
13922 2021-07-29 21:26:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0  5449.9892  5444.9467   5426.57
13923 2021-07-29 21:28:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0  5449.9914  5445.4061   5427.08
13924 2021-07-29 21:30:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0  5450.3931  5446.0056   5427.55

[13926 rows x 8 columns]
```

How to resolve this . please help?

Comment: Thankyou Andrej for edit the post in prefferred format

Comment: Is there anybody to help me out?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you want the dataframes combined.  Do you want the 1 minute data added to the 2 minute data?  Do you want the 1 minute data resampled as 2 minute data?   Do you want them interlaced in the dataframe, sorted by time?  As a specific example, please give four or five actual lines of data *from each of the two original dataframes (as dataframes),* and *then show* exactly *how you want those same four or five lines to look* in the final dataframe.  That should help clarify for me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Daniel Sir  I want to merge 2 data frames . First data frame  consists of historical data of crude for 2 month till now ,say df3 and  getting the data  to this df3 by return  value of function as "data" and output of df3 is shown as output of historical data above. Another datframe stores 1 min data generating from now and    I named as df and which contains ohlc value of 1 min data generated from tick by tick.  I want this df data to be clubbed with df3  with   sequentially adding index from the last index row of df3 ie, from 13924 row

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have one dataframe, call it **`df0`**, that looks something like this:

```sh
                  Date    Open    High     Low   Close
0  2021-07-29 21:12:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
1  2021-07-29 21:14:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
2  2021-07-29 21:16:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
3  2021-07-29 21:18:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
4  2021-07-29 21:20:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
5  2021-07-29 21:22:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
6  2021-07-29 21:24:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
7  2021-07-29 21:26:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
8  2021-07-29 21:28:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
9  2021-07-29 21:30:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
```

and another dataframe, call it **`df1`**, that looks something like this:

```sh
                  Date    Open    High     Low   Close
0  2021-07-29 21:40:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
1  2021-07-29 21:41:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
2  2021-07-29 21:42:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
3  2021-07-29 21:43:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
4  2021-07-29 21:44:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
5  2021-07-29 21:45:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
6  2021-07-29 21:46:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
7  2021-07-29 21:47:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
8  2021-07-29 21:48:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
9  2021-07-29 21:49:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
```

And you want a new dataframe, call it **`dfnew`** to look like this:

```sh
                   Date    Open    High     Low   Close
0   2021-07-29 21:12:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
1   2021-07-29 21:14:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
2   2021-07-29 21:16:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
3   2021-07-29 21:18:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
4   2021-07-29 21:20:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
5   2021-07-29 21:22:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
6   2021-07-29 21:24:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
7   2021-07-29 21:26:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
8   2021-07-29 21:28:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
9   2021-07-29 21:30:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
10  2021-07-29 21:40:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
11  2021-07-29 21:41:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
12  2021-07-29 21:42:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
13  2021-07-29 21:43:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
14  2021-07-29 21:44:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
15  2021-07-29 21:45:00  5453.0  5454.0  5450.0  5452.0
16  2021-07-29 21:46:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
17  2021-07-29 21:47:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
18  2021-07-29 21:48:00  5450.0  5454.0  5450.0  5453.0
19  2021-07-29 21:49:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0
```

If this is *not* the question you are asking, let me know.

---

If this *is* the what you are trying to accomplish, you can do it like this:

```py
dfnew = pd.concat([df0,df1])
dfnew.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

Comment: @AnandtsKerala regarding your comment ("But df1 data is continuous poll data ...") my appologies; it is very difficult for me to understand your description of the problem.  The best thing to help me understand is to show me (as I have done above) **what `df0` and `df1` look like, and what you want `dfnew` to look like, at each step in the continuous polling process, for at least the first 4 steps of polling.**   This means please show me what these three (`df0`, `df1`, and `dfnew`) should look like *at each of the first 4 steps in the polling process.*

Comment: df0 (will poll only once) :0  2021-07-29 21:14:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
df1(instant data per min: ) .After 1 min again df1 will be polled with index 0. 0  2021-07-29 21:15:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0                                                              dfnew                                                       
0  2021-07-29 21:14:00  5450.0  5452.0  5449.0  5451.0
1  2021-07-29 21:15:00  5453.0  5453.0  5450.0  5450.0   
2  2021-07-29 21:16:00  5458.0  5459.0  5443.0  5455.0                                                    
3  2021-07-29 21:16:00         df1

Comment: To clarify, after one minute `df1` will look like this: `0 2021-07-29 21:15:00 5453.0 5453.0 5450.0 5450.0`   After two minutes, will `df1` have one row or two?  Will it look like case A: `0 2021-07-29 21:16:00 5458.0 5459.0 5443.0 5455.0` or will it look like case B: `0 2021-07-29 21:15:00 5453.0 5453.0 5450.0 5450.0` `1 2021-07-29 21:16:00 5458.0 5459.0 5443.0 5455.0` ??

Comment: Sir Thankyou for reply.  After two minute, Iam getting only one row in df1 , ie; CASE-A , eventhough 1 min candle data ,from which Iam creating df1, have 2 rows with time incremented on minute basis.